# How can I run a intensive task async?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am new to JS async. I was playing around when I come up with this problem. I made a Promise object which is supposed to do a long while loop async.

```
document.querySelector("#set").addEventListener("click", async ()=>{

    const message = await doItEasy(1000000000);
    outputField.textContent = "Hey"; //I thought that this should bimmediatelyly done after above
    outputField.textContent = message;


});

function doItEasy(count){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (count < 0){
            throw new Error("Negative not accepted!");
        }

        let i = 0;
        while(i < count){
            i += 1;
        }
        resolve("Wow!");
    });
}
```

I expected when I start the loop it will be done in the background and my website is usable and smooth. But that is not the case as when the process starts everything freezes!

Am I getting the Promise and async concepts wrong?

Comment: Promises are tools to *manage* asynchronous code. They don't make synchronous code asynchronous.

Comment: And `await` makes a function *wait* until the promise is resolved (which seems to be the opposite of what you want to do)

Comment: In order to avoid blocking the main thread of execution (and therefore keep your application responsive) - and if you wish to keep your long-running task on the main thread of execution (foregoing eg. WebWorkers) - you need to cooperatively yield periodically from your long-running task. To do this you could make the long-running task periodically yield by puttting continuation of the loop into a `setTimeout` (for example) callback.